# World's longest purpose-built pedestrian tunnel?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids, walking, tunnels

Where is the world's longest publicly accessible purpose-built pedestrian tunnel?

Wikipedia has:

- [List of long tunnels by type, bicycle and pedestrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_long_tunnels_by_type#Bicycle_and_Pedestrian).  This is incomplete, as the only long pedestrian tunnel I've been in, the [1.6 km Niwärch tunnel](http://www.musee-des-bisses.ch/de/suone/niwarch) ([photo](http://zufussunterwegs.blogspot.co.uk/2015_07_01_archive.html)), was unlisted until I added it.  Worse, many of the entries are not pedestrian tunnels, but tunnels for disused railways now open to the public.  That's cheating.
- A [category on pedestrian tunnels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pedestrian_tunnels), which is even more incomplete (only 13 entries!).

Where is the longest purpose-built pedestrian tunnel in the world?  By a pedestrian tunnel, I mean a tunnel that, when built, was not designed for anything larger than a pedestrian or possibly cyclists.  For example, the Niwärch tunnel counts; built for water + human but has always been publicly accessible, but does not fit anything larger than a pedestrian (the watercourse is less than a metre wide).  Disused railways that are now open to foot and bike traffic don't count.  For the purpose of my question, it should be a simple tunnel connecting A to B; large networks of underground pathways such as the Toronto PATH do not count, for the same reason that the Shanghai Metro does not count as the world's longest railway tunnel.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You could edit the wikipedia entry to add the Niwärch tunnel.

Comment: @Max I could.  Adding all the other pedestrian tunnels I've been in but where I don't remember the name or exact location is harder!

Comment: @gerrit you might like to know https://www.tripadvisor.pt/Attraction_Review-g188636-d3597755-Reviews-St_Anna_s_Tunnel_Pedestrians_Tunnel-Antwerp_Antwerp_Province.html Probably not on list of longest, since it's only 500mts but very, very intersting pedestrian tunnel. It's in antwerp and goes under the river. It's accessible through wooden automatic stairs. Very nice.

Comment: http://cultursmag.com/video-get-set-for-the-pan-am-games-toronto-july-10-26/ who knows, claims are made... and then, really, who knows.

Comment: I freely concede it's not a pedestrian tunnel, but if Niwarch counts because it was built for water+human and has always been publicly accessible, then the [Standedge Canal Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standedge_Tunnels) fulfils the same criteria and tips the scales at just over 5km?

Comment: @MadHatter Good question.  Standegde is built for boats, Niwärch is not…

Comment: @MadHatter I would say Standedgde fails the *not designed for anything larger than a pedestrian* criterion, but it's quite interesting.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levada) there are Levadas with tunnels of more than 3km. The german entry even speaks of a tunnel with 5.1 km. Unfortunately I couldn't find any other sources, that's why I won't put it as an answer, but maybe someone else can verify. This would fit your criteria, right?

Comment: @martin.koeberl Yes, provided there is a trail along with it, which there usually is (needs maintenance after all).  Levada = acecquia?

Comment: @gerrit I agree with you about Standedge, but perhaps more interesting is that, lacking a towpath like most other canal tunnels, *it was designed for the [source of motive power to be human legs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legging_(canals)) - so nearly pedestrian, and yet so definitely not!

Comment: Are you including those built in city subway systems? Toronto's PATH underground passenger system is about 30 km long, although it also added elevated and at grade walkways.

Comment: @Dorothy That's the total length of interconnected pathways.  No, I don't include that, for the same reason that the London, Paris, or Moscow subways do not top the list of "world's longest railway tunnels".

Comment: Although Toronto's are purpose built (it's the brutal winter weather). The New York City subway system did the same, pedestrian tunnels, but nowhere near the length you want, and long abandoned. Is you criterion only pedestrians, and only to get from here to there?

Comment: @Dorothy Yes, it is.

Comment: Would you count the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_City,_Montreal as a pedestrian-only tunnel system? For sure not accessible by cars and 32km length in total.

Comment: @Sebastian That appears to be like the Toronto PATH, so no.

Comment: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sint-Annatunnel (in Dutch unfortunately) in Antwerp and is commonly know as the 'voetgangerstunnel' or translated as the pedestrian tunnel, 572 meters long and designed for pedestrians but also for cyclists.

Comment: Are you sure Niwärch tunnel isn't actually the longest pedestrian tunnel?

Comment: @JonathanReez Not at all, but if they are, they surely don't market it very well, as it appears quite unknown!

Comment: @gerrit I think most definitions don't care if it's 'purpose built' or not, which is why it's unknown.

Comment: Perhaps not what you're after, and maybe doesn't qualify due to being a 'network', but the [121-km long Củ Chi tunnel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%E1%BB%A7_Chi_tunnels) is worth noting. Since the criteria is continuous length, you'd have to work out what the longest continuous stretch in there is.

Comment: What about evacuation tunnels running parallel to for example the Channel Tunnel and highway tunnels under the Alps? They're purpose built for foot traffic, but are of course not meant to be used in anything but a dire emergency.

Comment: @jwenting I wouldn't consider emergency-only as *publicly accessible*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your conditions are quite strict - "Longest", "publicly accessible", AND "purpose-built".  A "simple tunnel connecting A to B".

There is indeed a tunnel that meets these criteria that at 1,635 metres is slightly longer than the one you've mentioned.  The tunnel itself IS publicly accessible, although at the current time it's entire length is not accessible - only part of it.

For this "simple tunnel", point A is North Korea.  Point B is South Korea.  And the tunnel is commonly known as the '[Third Infiltration Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Tunnel_of_Aggression)'. It was built to allow "pedestrians" (in the form of North Korean soldiers) to travel from North Korea into South Korea.  The southern end of the tunnel is currently open to the public (with restrictions around nationalities that can visit, but still...) and you can travel some way into the tunnel below the DMZ between the two countries.

Two additional, much longer tunnels in the same area meet all of your criteria except for not being publicly accessible.  The [first and second Infiltration Tunnels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Demilitarized_Zone#Incursion_tunnels) are both around 3.5km long and were purpose-built for "pedestrians". The forth Infiltration Tunnel rounds out the set, but is only around 2km long.

Comment: I'm amazed that ANY parts of those infiltration tunnels are accessible.

Comment: Great find! The reasons to build a tunnel just for pedestrians scarce but war is probably one of them!

Comment: It's funny they actually have a fourth tunnel as well! Granted not as long as the other three.

Answer (score 6):

The pedestrian-part of the [Galleria ENEL Alpe Croppi di Lago](https://map.geo.admin.ch/?lang=en&topic=ech&bgLayer=ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe&layers=ch.swisstopo.zeitreihen,ch.bfs.gebaeude_wohnungs_register,ch.bav.haltestellen-oev,ch.swisstopo.swisstlm3d-wanderwege,KML%7C%7Chttps:%2F%2Fpublic.geo.admin.ch%2FV08dxMkNTOqph1y-lM2gzA&layers_opacity=1,1,1,0.8,1&layers_visibility=false,false,true,true,true&layers_timestamp=20101231,,,,&E=2647120.48&N=1098968.84&zoom=9) appears to be around 2.8 km long (and reportedly only around 1.8 metre high in places, though I'm not sure about the height in general).  It is used by a variant route of the [GTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Traversata_delle_Alpi) and other hiking routes.  It is described by [this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3dcY2YZKI0).

Comment: I can confirm that this one appears to tick all the boxes in the question. Source: I went through it a few years ago.

Comment: @Somewanderingyeti Is it really only around 1.8 metre high throughout?  That would make passing through for me rather uncomfortable, even moreso if I'm wearing my ridiculously large backpack.  I can bend occasionally but walking bent for more than half an hour, with a heavy backpack, could be quite unpleasant.

Comment: It will be a higher throughout. I'm a few centimeters short of 1.8m and could pass without worrying about bumping into anything. Don't worry unless you happen to be sumo-sized.

Comment: @Somewanderingyeti Good to hear I don't need to bring a helmet to cross this tunnel!

Answer (score 2):

There's a pedestrian tunnel [under construction under Løvstakken](https://www.bt.no/nyheter/lokalt/i/Eo3zL3/bergen-faar-verdens-lengste-sykkeltunnel-i-2023), in Bergen, Norway. The length is 2900m. It's scheduled to open in 2023.

> Parallelt med traseen bygges det en gang- og sykkeltunnel. Tunnelen vil bli en toveis bane med en bredde på seks meter. 3,5 meter blir sykkelfelt og 2,5 meter blir fortau.

> In paralell with the [light rail] tunnel, a separate pedestrian and biking tunnel is being built. The tunnel will have two lanes [for bikes and pedestrians], with a total width of 6 meters. 3.5 meters will be bike lanes, and 2.5 meters for pedestrians.

Answer (score 1):

[Tunnel de la Croix-Rousse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_de_la_Croix-Rousse) in Lyon, France, is a pair of tunnels, the first one for cars, the other one for sustainable transport (pedestrians, cyclists, busses). Their length is 1782m.

Comment: The buses make it ineligible, by the OP's criteria ("*not designed for anything larger than a pedestrian or possibly cyclists*").